# How to assign QML file to MainWindow/Application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

**SITUATION**

I have my `main.cpp` here

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "root.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    testApp::Root data;

    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataContext", &data);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and my `main.qml`  here

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World!!!")
}
```

**PROBELM**

whenever i start my app, it does not assign the values from `main.qml` to my main window.

for example:
 the properties **width**, **height** in main.qml have the values **640**, **480**. But whenever i start the app, my window is much smaller(and yes i have tried to give them different values)

**QUESTION**

how to say the program: he should use main.qml for my main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using QQuickView then the root has to be a QQuickItem as Item, Rectangle, etc. since QQuickView is a window.

If instead you want to root Window or ApplicationWindow then you must use QQmlApplicationEngine.

In your case there are 2 windows: One the QQuickView and the other the Window.

Considering the above you have the following 2 options:

1. QQuickView

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    testApp::Root data;
    view.view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataContext", &data);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.setTitle("Hello World!!!")
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480
}
```

2. QQmlApplicationEngine

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    testApp::Root data;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataContext", &data);
    engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World!!!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll accept you answer but could you please explain why is qt not recognizing the main.qml. It says that "no such file or directory"

Comment: @Zer0 If you use QUrl::fromLocalFile() then it is expected that the main.qml is next to the executable so copy the main.qml in the build folder, if you don't want to do it then create a qresource and add the main.qml there, then just you change `QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml")` to `QUrl("qrc:/main.qml")`

Comment: @Zer0 Generally when you create a project with Qt Creator it already creates the .qrc and uses QQmlApplicationEngine so you should not modify it if you do not want to have this kind of problem.